# Show that the number of edges is less than or equal to the product of minimum vertex cover and maximum independent set for a bipartite graph G

Tags: graph-theory

Show that $$|E(G)| ≤ \alpha_{0} (G) \beta_{0} (G)$$ where $\alpha_{0} (G)$ is the maximum independent set number and $\beta_{0} (G)$ is the minimum vertex cover number for a bipartite graph G.

I tried an approach using the fact that arithematic mean greater than or equal to the geometric mean (applied over $\alpha_{0} (G)$ and $\beta_{0} (G)$, since the sum is n), but that got me no where. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Consider $G$ be the complete graph with $n=4$ (i.e. the square with diagonals) then $|E(G)|=6$ but the product of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is $3$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention - G is a bipartite graph. I've edited the question appropriately

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I solved it (I asked the question without logging in): let the bipartite graph be G[X, Y]. Let $m = |X|$, $n = |Y|$. Let $p = max(m, n)$, $q = min(m, n)$.

Then $\alpha_{0} >= p$ (since no element in one partition is adjacent to any element in the same partition) and $\beta_{0} >= q$ (since to cover every edge, it is enough, but necessary, to include all the vertices in the smaller partition).

So $$\alpha_{0}\beta_{0} ≥ pq = mn ≥ |E|$$

Comment: I think your argument on $\beta_0$ only implies that $\beta_0 \leq q$.  Also, where do you get $mn \geq |E|$ from ?  Is your graph complete bipartite ?

Comment: It's not complete bipartite, but if it was then $mn = |E|$. So any other bipartite graph will have $mn ≥ |E|$.

Comment: You're right sorry !  Brain cramp !  What about $\beta_0 \geq q$ ?